# Can someone see the proof for that(number theory)

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Please this is very important to me I would be so happy if someone is able to help... :)

Let $I$ be a squarefree, natural and even number and $F$ the product of all primes $q$ where $(q-1) \mid I$.

So for example if $I = 2 \cdot 3 = 6$, then $F = 42 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7$ because those three primes are the only ones where $(q - 1)$ is dividing $I = 6$.

So far so good; Now I want all combinations $(p, q)$, where $p \mid I$, $q \mid F$ and $p \mid q - 1$, so in this example $(2, 3)$, $(2, 7)$ and $(3, 7)$;

Now what I want to show is: Show that there is at least one $(p, q)$ combination for every $p \mid I$, so in the example one for $p = 2$ and one for $p = 3$.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I can bring a counterexample.

Let $I=2*7=14$ and $F=2*3=6$.

There is no combination for $p=7$

Comment: Indeed, $7 \mid 14$ but $7 \nmid 1$.